# tmux - how-to enable automatic switching from 80 to 132 columns and back

Tags: terminal, putty, tmux

Currently in our terminal based accounting system, clients mostly use putty (0.61) and when a report is viewed in the terminal, an escape code is issued that kicks the screen from 80 to 132 columns if the report is over 80 columns.  This works with 'screen' and from a plain ssh session.  So far I haven't been able to find a way to get tmux to pass the same escape codes through to the terminal software.  It must be capturing it and sending it to /dev/null?  In the server configuration for 'xterm', vt100 and ansi, I can see the escape codes used.  Is there a way to allow these codes to pass-through tmux so that the terminal or putty software gets the code and does the column numbers switching?

For xterm and vt100 the 132 column escape code is:  (ESC)[?3h
and the return to 80 columns is: (ESC)[?3l

I love tmux speed and tmux.conf clarity of configs over 'screen' and 'screenrc', but this one item is keeping me from switching users over.

Comment: I would check on the `tmux-users` mailing list (https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tmux-users). My feeling is that this constitutes a type of pane-resize (since all `tmux` windows are a collection of panes, even if the window only has a single pane), and `tmux` at this time doesn't provide a way to specify the absolute size of a pane: you can only increment or decrement a pane's current size.

Answer (score 2):

this is a pretty obscure vtXX feature and would mess with other panes in the same tmux window, so this is not supported. If you can modify the application, you can have it send `\ePtmux;\e\e[?3h\e\\` to pass through a raw escape sequence to the underlying terminals (`\e`=Escape,`\\`=Backslash)